# Finite Math (Probability/Venn Diagram)

Tags: probability

13) A survey revealed that $25\%$ of people are entertained by reading books, $39\%$ are entertained by watching TV, and $36\%$ are entertained by both books and TV. What is the probability that a person will be entertained by either books or TV? Express the answer as a percentage.

Is this problem stated correctly? How can $36\%$ of the people be entertained by both books and TV, when only $25\%$ of the people are entertained by reading books?

**EDIT**

Here are two other questions from the exam, that the instructor said followed the same logic as the question above.

14) Of the coffee makers sold in an appliance store, $5.0\%$ have either a faulty switch or a defective cord, $1.6\%$ have a faulty switch, and $0.2\%$ have both defects. What is the probability that a coffee maker will have a defective cord? Express the answer as a percentage.

15) A survey of senior citizens at a doctor's office shows that $42\%$ take blood pressure-lowering medication, $45\%$ take cholesterol-lowering medication, and $13\%$ take both medications. What is the probability that senior citizen takes either blood pressure-lowering or cholesterol-lowering medication? Express the answer as a percentage.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is stated correctly. Usually, there'd be a problem: $25\%$ like TV, $75\%$ like books, and $50\%$ are entertained by both. In this case, since $25+39+36=100$, I am led to believe that the question should, when stated more rigorously, read:

> A survey revealed that $25\%$ of people are entertained **only by** reading books, $39\%$ are entertained by **only by** watching TV, and $36\%$ are entertained **only by** both books and TV. What is the probability that a person will be entertained by either books or TV?

Other than that, the question is fine.

**Edit:** In my example, i.e., $25\%$ like TV, $75\%$ like books, and $50\%$ are entertained by both, 
$$\mathrm{Pr(TV\cup Books)}=\mathrm{Pr(TV)}+\mathrm{Pr(Books)}-\mathrm{Pr(TV\cap Books)}\\
\implies \mathrm{Pr(TV\cup Books)}=0.25+0.75-0.50=0.5=50\%$$

Similarly, for your problem,
$$\mathrm{Pr(TV\cup Books)}=\mathrm{Pr(TV)}+\mathrm{Pr(Books)}-\mathrm{Pr(TV\cap Books)}\\
\implies \mathrm{Pr(TV\cup Books)}=0.25+0.39-0.36=0.28=28\%$$

Comment: I feel the question would only make sense, if it was stated "rigorously" as you put, otherwise it seems ambiguous. Anyways what answer do you get? And in your given example, do you mind walking through how to solve it?

Comment: @Jesse See my edited answer.

Comment: When $P(A \cap B) > P(A)$ does that imply that $P(A)$ is the probability for $A$ to strictly occur, otherwise the probability of obtaining $A$, be it solely $A$ or $A$ with $B$ is greater than the given $P(A)$? Which sounds odd... help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You use the inclusion-exclusion principle. $Pr(A \cup B) = Pr(A) + Pr(B) - Pr(A \cap B)$. Your exam questions are worded correctly and don't have the same problem as the original question you posed did. It always must be true that $Pr(A \cap B) \le min(Pr(A), Pr(B))$, since $A \cap B \subseteq A$ and $A \cap B \subseteq B$.

For question
14) Let $F$ denote the event of a faulty switch, and $D$ denote the event of a defective cord. You are told, $P(F \cup D) = 0.05, P(F) = 0.016$, and $P(F\cap D) = 0.002$. From the inclusion-exclusion principle you know

$P(F \cup D) = P(F) + P(D) - P(F \cap D) \Rightarrow P(D) = P(F \cup D) - P(F) + P(F \cap D) =$ $0.05 - 0.016 + 0.002 = 0.036$.

Question 15) Follow's a similar procedure (apply inclusion-exclusion principle) to get $.42 + .45 - 0.13 = 0.74$.

Comment: How would you show this on a Venn Diagram?

Comment: So is the question asking for the probability of the symmetric difference or the union ?

Comment: The question is asking about the union, you want to include the middle portion. While symmetric difference in this case would be $Pr(A) + Pr(B) - 2*Pr(A \cap B)$. Looking back my previous Venn Diagram explanation it seems it's slightly incorrect, ignore it. Sanath's description of the question is better, the original wording isn't the best. In any case, the question is just testing the 'inclusion-exclusion principle'.

Comment: This was an exam question, so if the wording is not good I would like to challenge it, but if the question is correct by the context/logic, I need to know how the logic leads to an unambiguous answer. Namely, what does $P(A \cap B) > P(A)$ imply?

Comment: ^ I lied haha, sorry I don't know what I was thinking you're right it's obviously not possible. See updated answer. Do challenge your instructor.

Comment: The inclusion-exclusion principle works, but only if you define A and B correctly. After re-reading it makes more sense for P(A) = 0.25 + 0.36 and P(B) = 0.39 + 0.36, thus $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$, which is trivially just sum of the three probabilities they gave.

Comment: I updated the original post, following that logic would you get $100\%$ for problem 15 as well? I may be able to challenge two of the questions.

Comment: No those questions unfortunately make sense, even though the original question you posed was poorly worded. I'll update the answer to explain how those questions work.

Comment: Problems 14 and 15 make sense because the probability of the intersection is less than or equal to the probability of the sets that make up the intersection?

Comment: Yes, the interpretation for problem 15 is if you called event A: patient takes BP med, and B: patient takes CL med, then when it says 42% take BP med it's taking into account both the people take take BP med exclusively and those who take both BP and CL med. A similar thing holds for the CL med, that's why you "double counted" the both CL and BP med if you do $Pr(A) + Pr(B)$ and hence you need to subtract off the probability of both taking BP and CL.

Comment: You can complain though, in the instructor indeed did tell you to follow "the logic for the above problem", then that problem was misleading because of the probabilities. Given the ambiguity you thought 42% meant those who only take BL (and didn't include those who took both BL and CL). It's worth a shot I suppose.